# Неправильная последовательность вывода текста в консоль с Event - transitionstart и transitionend, js

Tags: javascript, события

Я уже некоторое время не могу решить одну проблему с моим кодом. Я делаю приложение на cordova, и мне, в коде, нужно сделать обнаружение начала transition и его конец, я делаю это с помощью события transitionstart и transitionend. Код у меня длинный, по этому я покажу только важное.
Вот главный файл `main.js` где находятся события:

```
element.addEventListener('transitionstart', function(){
      console.log('start');
});
        
element.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
      console.log('end');
});
```

Потом у меня есть файл `animate.js`, в котором происходит анимация:
Функция `toLeft()` передвигает элемент в лево и меняет его ширину, функция `toRight()` передвигает
элемент в право и меняет его ширину, а последняя функция сначала выполняет функцию `toLeft()` а через 1.7s выполняет функцию `toRight()`. В первую и вторую функцию я передаю значения, от которых зависит на сколько пикселей элемент подвинется или поменяет свою ширину.

```
function toLeft(left){
         element.style.width = innerWidth + left + 'px';  
         element.style.marginLeft = 0 + 'px'; 
}
function toRight(right){
         element.style.width =  innerWidth + right + 'px';
         element.style.marginLeft = -right + 'px';
}
function toLeftAndRight(){
         setTimeout(()=>{ toLeft(); }, 0);
         setTimeout(()=>{ toRight(); }, 1700);
}
```

В файле css я добавил к анимированному элементу свойство `transition: 1.7s all`.
Так же в файле `main.js` у меня есть объект, которому я передаю значения для функций `toLeft()` и `toRight()`: Когда я передам только значение `left` выполнится функция `toLeft()`, если передам значение `right` выполнится функия `toRight()`, а если передам два значения то выполнится функция `toLeftAndRight()`.

```
obj.animate({
    right: 200,
    left: 300
});
```

Когда я вызываю этот метод объекта, выполняется анимация с указанными свойствами. Как видите, я передал два значения, тогда выполнится функция `toLeftAndRight()`.
Теперь главное - после каждого вызова этого объекта с методом `animate`, значения именно его последнего вызова передаются в функцию `save` со значениями `left, right`, и сохраняются в localStorage:

```
function save(left, right){
  localStorage.setItem('animate', JSON.stringify({left: left, right: right}));
}
```

Теперь, для чего это нужно - у меня таких анимаций будет не мало, так как это скорее можно назвать игрой, где нужно работать в основном с текстом, и где при клике эта анимация меняется. Eсть функция которая считает клики, и в соответствии с определенным кликом, например кликом 41 (когда пользователь делает уже 41 клик :D), меняет анимацию. Если пользователь вышел из приложения допустим, после 41 клика, то значения объекта с методом `animate` которые должны были выполнится только для клика 41 сохранятся в localStorage, а когда пользователь зайдет назад, то в соответствии с тем, какие последние значения были записаны в localstorage, выполнится соответственная анимация.
Проблема в том, что события `transitionstart` и `transitionend`:

```
element.addEventListener('transitionstart', function(){
  console.log('start');
});
    
element.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
  console.log('end');
});
```

работают не так. В консоль выводится `start` когда анимация началась и `end` когда она закончилась. Я передал два значения в объект с методом `animate`, значения: `left, right` тогда у меня выполняется функция `toLeftAndRight()`, то есть, в консоль мне должно вывести сначала `start` потом `end` потом снова `start` и потом `end`, так и происходит, но когда пользователь вышел, а за тем зашел обратно на страницу, и анимация на которой он остановился начинает выполнятся, то консоль пишет `start` потом `start` а вот за тем уже `end` и опять `end`, а правильно должно было `start -> end -> start -> end`. И это происходит именно когда выполняется функция `toLeftAndRight()`, когда выполняется только `toLeft()` или `toRight()` проблем нет. Я вообще не могу понять, почему такая последовательность `start->start->end->end` именно когда анимация выполяется в соответствии со значениями из localSrorage, должно же быть `start->end->start->end` или я ошибаюсь? Я пытался всё хорошо объяснить и выбрал самые важные участки кода, надеюсь кто-то знает в чем я ошибся, буду очень благодарен если кто-то поможет, мне это очень важно.
Eщё на всякий случай, покажу как я выполняю анимацию в соответствии со значениями из Localstorage (Когда пользователь заходит назад на страницу):

```
 let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('animate'));
 obj.animate({
   left: obj.left,
   right: obj.right
 });
```

Comment: недостаточно логов. Нужно добавить какой именно старт, тогда будет ясно какая именно анимация запускается

Comment: собственно вывод вполне похож на правду, из-за попытки ручной синхронизации таймера и анимации. сделай между ними разрыв больше - и скорее всего чаще будет попадаться "правильная" последовательность

Comment: Спасибо, да, у меня больше функционала, и есть какой именно старт, и ещё много деталей, я простро привёл лёгкий пример, что бы не запуать других, было бы много...) Я так понимаю я не совсем правильно сделал с секундами, наверное действительно стоит как-то переписать... просто важно именно что бы было 1.7 сек. В браузере работает в 90% хорошо, а когда попроьбывал на ардроиде, нет))

Comment: возможно вместо таймаутов стоит использовать те же самые события, если важна очередность

Comment: попробовал*. Да, тоже задумался, так и сделаю, спасибо большое)